# Словари в python, добавление значений

Tags: python-3.x, словари, dict

Есть два словаря

```
dict_1 = [{'id': 1, 'value': someValue}, {'id': 2, 'value': someValue2}]
dict_2 = [{'id': 1, 'anotherValue': another}, {'id': 2, 'anotherValue': another}]
```

как сравнить их ключи, в данном случае id и обьеденить в один
чтобы получилось что-то на подобе

```
result_dict = [{'id': 1, 'value': someValue, 'anotherValue': another}, {'id': 2, 'value': someValue2, 'anotherValue': another}]
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29694826/7485582

Answer (score 0):

можно решить в лоб:

```
dict_1 = [{'id': 1, 'value': 11}, {'id': 2, 'value': 12}]
dict_2 = [{'id': 1, 'anotherValue': 13}, {'id': 2, 'anotherValue': 14}]

tmp = {}

for obj in [dict_1, dict_2]:
    for elem in obj:
        if elem['id'] not in tmp:
            tmp[elem['id']] = elem
        else:
            tmp[elem['id']].update(elem)

res = [value for value in tmp.values()]

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант через промежуточный словарь словарей.

```
dict_1 = [{'id': 1, 'value': 'someValue'}, {'id': 2, 'value': 'someValue2'}]
dict_2 = [{'id': 1, 'anotherValue': 'another'}, {'id': 2, 'anotherValue': 'another2'}]

d = {x['id']:x.copy() for x in dict_1}
for x in dict_2:
    d[x['id']].update(x)
result_dict = list(d.values())

print(result_dict)
```

```
[{'id': 1, 'value': 'someValue', 'anotherValue': 'another'}, 
 {'id': 2, 'value': 'someValue2', 'anotherValue': 'another2'}]
```